# Call to a member function hashName() on array

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-8

and I have a problem with how to enter images into the data base, in the case of the presence of input fields that increase or decrease in the case of addition or deletion

[image]

This is the code for adding data to the database

```php
$products = $request->day_book_id;
for ($i=0; $i<count($products); $i++) {
    $items = new Daybooks_units();

    $items->debit= $request->debit[$i];
    $items->creditor= $request->creditor[$i];
    $items->data= $request->data[$i];
    $items->reference= $request->reference[$i];
    $items->files= $request->reference[$i];

    $items->files = uploadImage('filesDayBooks',$request->images)[$i];

    $items->dayBook_code= $request->dayBook_code[$i];
    $items->fullAccounting_id= $request->fullAccounting_id[$i];
    $items->day_book_id= $request->day_book_id[$i];
    $items->branch_id= $request->branch_id[$i];
    $items->save();
```

This is the code for the blade

```html
<td style="padding:3px" >
    <input type="text" class="search" name="search" required>

    <select class="form-control search_list getData" id="search_list"  name="fullAccounting_id[]"></select>
    @error('fullAccounting_id')
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {{ $message }}
        </div>
    @enderror
</td>
<td style="display:none" >
    <input type="text" value=" " class=" form-control putParentId" name="ParentOfAccounting_manual_id[]">
</td>
<td style="display:none">
    <input type="text" value=" " class=" form-control putCode" name="code_accountingManuals[]">
</td>
<td style="display:none">
    <input type="text" value=" " class=" form-control debtor_creditor" name="debtor_creditor[]">
</td>
<td style="padding:3px">
    <input type="text" value="0" class=" form-control totaldebit" onchange="getTotalRowPrice(this , '{{-500}}' )" name="debit[]">
    @error('debit')
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {{ $message }}
        </div>
    @enderror
</td>
<td style="width:100px;">
    <input type="text" onchange="getTotalRowPrice(this , '{{-500}}' )" value="0" class=" form-control totalcreditor" name="creditor[]">
    @error('creditor')
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {{ $message }}
        </div>
    @enderror
</td>
<td style="padding:3px">
    <input type="text" value="" class=" form-control" name="data[]">
</td>
<td style="width:100px;">
    <select name="branch_id[]" required class="form-control">
        <option></option>
        @foreach($costCenters as $costCent)
            <option value="{{$costCent->id}}">{{$costCent->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    @error('branch_id')
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {{ $message }}
        </div>
    @enderror
</td>
<td style="padding:3px">
    <input type="text" class="form-control " name="reference[]" value="">
</td>
<td style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control " name="id_unit[]" value="{{ $id_unit }}">
</td>
<td style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control " name="daybooks_units[]" value="daybooks_units">
</td>
<td style="padding:3px">
    <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple class="form-control" id="customFile">
</td>
<td style="padding:3px">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="add" id="add" value="add" style="color: white">
</td>
```

The function works smoothly if no images are inserted, but when images are uploaded, this error appears

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your custom (not shared) `uploadeImage` function does, but the error SHOULD be here:

```php
// You coded
$items->files = uploadImage('filesDayBooks',$request->images)[$i];

// It should be
$items->files = uploadImage('filesDayBooks',$request->images[$i]);
```

If that is not the error, please share `uploadeImage` code

Comment: $items->files = uploadImage('filesDayBooks',$request->images[$i]);
In this code that I wrote, it stores the values for the first paste in the data base and ignores the rest of the rows that follow it

Comment: It seems that the problem with uploadeImage is this function that I found on a website. In fact, I do not remember it, but it was explaining that it was used to upload images, so I used it, but if you have an idea or a function that will bring the required result, I hope you will share it with me.

Comment: This error means that your some of your `images[]` were empty.